# PHP - Oracle - special characters - NLS_LANG?

Tags: php, ajax, joomla, oracle10g, xampp

When I connect with sqlplus (windows 7, cmd) to a oracle database and query with umlauts (ü, ö, ä) I don't get anything back.

I queried for the NLS_LANG and got following back:

```
AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P1
```

The oracle database runs on a linux distribution. So I opened the cmd box and entered

```
set NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P1
```

and repeated the query - once more without success. Then I got following hint:

```
set NLS_LANG=German_Germany.WE8PC850'
```

This worked - finally. But I want to use the query statement in joomla. And now I don't know how to handle with this problem. I use oci8 and oracle10g. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in a post from @ddallala. Here is the link: [utf8_decode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2426788/1778407)

```
utf8_decode($_POST['search_name_with_special_character'])
```

was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Oracle docs you can set the NLS_LANG forever (rather than having to set it every time you connect) by running the 'setenv' command in Linux:

```
setenv NLS_LANG German_Germany.WE8PC850
```

Link: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12102_01/books/AnyInstAdm784/AnyInstAdmPreInstall18.html

This will only work of course if you have access to the server. If you do not, there may be some way of calling the 'set NLS_LANG=German_Germany.WE8PC850' after every time Joomla connects to the database, but I don't know anything about Joomla so I can't help you there!

Comment: Remember that the XAMPP server is running on Windows and the oracle database, on which I haven't access, is running on Linux.